# Conditional calculation of mean

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to calculate means of a data frame for each factor, but only if certain condition is met. For example, I have this data frame:

```
> df <- data.frame(name = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 20), 
                 variable1 = rep(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA), 10), 
                 variable2 = rep(c(2, NA, 2, 2, 2, 2), 10), 
                 variable3 = rep(c(NA, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), 10))

> table(df$name, df$variable1)

     1
  A 20
  B 20
  C 10

> table(df$name, df$variable2)

     2
  A 20
  B 10
  C 20

> table(df$name, df$variable3)

     3
  A 10
  B 20
  C 20
```

I can easily calculate means for each variable with `dplyr` in a following way:

```
means <- df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
> means
Source: local data frame [3 x 4]

  name variable1 variable2 variable3
1    A         1         2         3
2    B         1         2         3
3    C         1         2         3
```

However, what I want is to only calculate means if there are 11 or more observations, otherwise put `NA`'s in respective cells. In other words, the result should look like this:

```
  name variable1 variable2 variable3
1    A         1         2        NA
2    B         1        NA         3
3    C        NA         2         3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We could create a function (`f1`) which will do the mean `if` the number of non-`NA` values is greater than 11 (`sum(!is.na(x))>11`) or else we get `NA`.  I am using `NA_real_` as the default `NA` would be of logical class and there may be clash of class in some packages.

Using `dplyr`, we group by `name` and use the function (`f1`) within `summarise_each`

```
f1 <- function(x) if(sum(!is.na(x))>11) mean (x, na.rm=TRUE) else NA_real_
library(dplyr) 
df  %>% 
     group_by(name) %>%
     summarise_each(funs(f1))
```

Or a similar approach using `data.table` would be to convert the `data.frame` to `data.table` (`setDT(df)`).  We loop through the columns (`lapply(.SD, ..)`), use the same function grouped by `name`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,  lapply(.SD, f1), by = name]
#   name variable1 variable2 variable3
#1:    A         1         2        NA
#2:    B         1        NA         3
#3:    C        NA         2         3
```

Comment: That was fast! Thank you very much. Is there any way to do the same in dplyr? It's not a strict condition, just out of curiosity.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks, I was updating the function.

Comment: @MikhailBalyasin do you find the `dplyr` syntax more intuitive?

Comment: @DavidArenburg, yes, because I never worked with data.table, but do have some experience with dplyr.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative transforming previously the data from wide to long.

```
library(reshape2)
df1 <- melt(df, id.vars = c("name")) # From wide to long
df1 <- df1 %>% group_by(name, variable) %>% 
       filter(n()>10) %>%
       summarize(mean = mean(value))
```

Long format output:

```
   name  variable mean
1    A variable1    1
2    A variable2    2
3    A variable3   NA
4    B variable1    1
5    B variable2   NA
6    B variable3    3
7    C variable1   NA
8    C variable2    2
9    C variable3    3
```

Wide format output:

```
dcast(df1,  name ~ variable, value.var = "mean")

  name variable1 variable2 variable3
1    A         1         2        NA
2    B         1        NA         3
3    C        NA         2         3
```